# How to set deep nested property without re-render the all component tree with onpush in angular?

Tags: angular

I built simple menu component in angular.

`menu` - is the `ul` and `menu-item` is the `li`.

The data is sturcture like this:

```
   menu = [
    {
      text: "level-1",
      children: [
        { text: "level-1-1" },
        {
          text: "level-1-2",
          children: [
            { text: "level-1-2-1" },
            { text: "level-1-2-2" },
            { text: "level-1-2-3" }
          ]
        },
        { text: "level-1-3" }
      ]
    },
    { text: "level-2" },
    { text: "level-3" }
  ];
```

So the menu component is go for each item and build the menu recursively.

The problem is I want to set `active` to the item **after** it complete render the menu.

By clicking on the button I set somewhere item to active.

The problem is not working because I set change detection to `onPush` of course. but it's not the problem because the components should be on push and still be working.

I try two things:
one is change directly on the object:

```
this.menu[0].children[1].children[1].active = true;
```

But because onPush it doesn't works.

the other way I was try to build again the object structure it's works but it will re-render the entire components which is bad thing.

Do you know a clever way of how to do it with onPush and not re-render all the components again?

[Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-mirzakhani-o8tb7?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:699-750)

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you need 2nd approach (Rebuild the object i.e. change ref of object). But it will re-render entire tree.

To fix that, you need to use trackBy with *ngFor with some kind of unchange and unique data like id. That will keep track of changed data and will not re-render unchanged rows or data

```js
trackByFn(index, item){
    // return index; 
    return item.id; // or any constant prop
}
```

```html
<menu-item *ngFor="let item of menu; trackBy:trackByFn" [item]="item"></menu-item>
```